# Create a trapezoid that has transparent borders and background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

I know with some [border tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), I could create trapezoid shape. I can also set its border-color to rgba(r,g,b,a) to make it transparent.

But is it possible to create trapezoid that has transparent borders and background ?

See below image for an example,

[image]

Currently, I use some png images to achieve this effect，but generating images of different sizes is really boring work，so I'm looking for a css soluation。

Comment: Nice challenge! I'll see what I can do...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I think it's overkill, but it can be done like this:

## [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3749727)

**HTML**:

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='content'><!--stuff here--></div>
    <div class='label l1'></div>
    <div class='label l2'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px; /* whole thing breaks if this is not a multiple of 100px */
    border: solid .5em rgba(0,0,255,.5);
    border-bottom: solid 0px transparent;
    margin: 7em auto 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
.outer:before, .outer:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    height: .5em;
    background: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
    content: ''
}
.outer:before { left: -.5em; width: 15%; border-left: solid .5em transparent; }
.outer:after { right: -.5em; width: 55%; border-right: solid .5em transparent; }
.content {
    padding: .5em;
    margin: 1.5em;
    border-bottom: solid 1.5em transparent;
    background: lightblue;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
.label {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 3em;
}
.l1 { left: 15%; }
.l2 { left: 30%; }
.label:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -.5em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5em;
    border: solid .5em rgba(0,0,255,.5);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    content: '';
}
.l1:before { left: 9%; transform: skewX(30deg); }
.l2:before { right: 9%; transform: skewX(-30deg); }
```

---

It works in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari (I was afraid to test it in IE9, though both `transform` and `background-clip` work) but only if the `width` for `.outer` has a value that's a multiple of `100px`.

Unless using a `width` that's a multiple of `100px`, it only works in Firefox and Chrome (there is a little glitch in Chrome - could be fixed by using a WebKit-only left to right linear gradient that sharply goes from transparent to that semitransparent blue really close to the start).

[image: Chrome]

It breaks in Opera and Safari (if using a `width` that is not a multiple of `100px`):

[image: Opera] [image: Safari]

Comment: Using the `500px` value for the `width` of `.outer`, yes. But if you change that value into let's say `32em`, then it breaks just like in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the bg color and border colors transparent, but the borders will not follow the shape of the trapezoid:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/UZbJh/1/

So your best bet is to stick with the pngs for now.